# how to describe the parameters of a hashmap in swagger v3?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, spring-restcontroller, springfox

I need to customize the request body in swagger, because in my controller I get a `HashMap<String, String>` and in the documentation it appears as

[image]

I would like to inform which properties I want to receive in the hashmap and I don't know how to annotate.

`My Controller`

```
@PostMapping("/add")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Atendimento create(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> param) throws Exception {
    return service.create(param);
}
```

Comment: Well, if you need to see the model, just use it in the controller :) What's the motivation of using Hashmap ?

Comment: i can't pull out the hashmap, i just need to say what properties i want to receive in it.

Comment: What keeps you from moving to a propely typed model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the following will help you, but still the same question stands why you are not using a model (DTO) class directly instead.

Here is an example using Kotlin, which can help you:

```kotlin
@RestController
class SampleController {

    data class RequestBodyMetaData(
        val key1: String,
        val key2: String,
        val key3: String,
    )

    @PostMapping("/sample")
    fun sample(
        @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
            content = [
                Content(
                    schema = Schema(implementation = RequestBodyMetaData::class),
                )
            ]
        )
        @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
        sample: Map<String, String>,
    ) {
    }
}
```

[image: Screen capture from the sample result]